# Typescript giving Type '"Test"' is not assignable to type 'undefined'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a simple object having two fields name and age, initially those are defined as undefined and later in the code the value will get assigined

```
const s={
    name:undefined,
    age:undefined
}
s.name="Test" //error
```

when I am trying to assign any value to my attributes it gives me typescript error

`Type '"Test"' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.`

Can anyone explain why I am getting this error in typescript and how to fix it

Comment: any reason for specifying it as undefined instead of null ?

Comment: Did you want to make the type optional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not explicitly define a type for `s`, so the compiler tries to infer one, based on the provided values.

The inferred type of `s` is:

```
{
  name: undefined;
  age: undefined;
}
```

You have set an explicit type like so:

```
type User = {
  name: string | undefined;
  age: number | undefined;
};

const s: User = {
    name: undefined,
    age: undefined
};
s.name = "Test"; //should work
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the inferred type of `s` you can see that it is

```
{
    name:undefined;
    age:undefined;
}
```

[image]

TypeScript can't infer that any other type might be allowed here because you didn't supply that info.

Create a type:

```
interface Person{
    name: string | undefined;
    age: number | undefined;
}
```

then declare `s` with this type:

```
const s:Person = {
    name: undefined;
    age: undefined;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQyxyIcAthAFzIZhSgDmyAPsgK4gAmEMoEXANxEScRtVLtyAI2isO3XvyEEAvgQQ46tGuijZcAXnwjiZSjU48+IAQBpTyMRKtLbXNQQwA6cymMARAAqEHQByAD0EaRYyNBQWFAEQA)